# Result stop showing in the IDLE shell after using reload(sys)

Tags: python-2.7, character-encoding, python-idle

In the python 2.7 shell, after I do the following:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

the shell stop showing the result. If I type `print('hello world')`, nothing is shown.

By the way, why `reload(sys)` is essential here? Without it the setdefaultencoding() cause an error?

Comment: And now you know why you shouldn't use that method.

Comment: any explain will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The question about needing `reload(sys)` has nothing to do with IDLE.  Read the last sentence of the 2.7 doc entry.

> sys.setdefaultencoding(name)
>
> Set the current default string encoding used by the Unicode implementation.
>   If name does not match any available encoding,
>   LookupError is raised. This function is only intended to be used by
>   the site module implementation and, where needed, by sitecustomize.
>   Once used by the site module, it is removed from the sys module’s
>   namespace.

You are not supposed to use the function.  In 3.x, it has been removed (or made invisible).  Hence the following from the standard Python console interpreter.

```
C:\Users\Terry>py
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> sys.setdefaultencoding
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'
```

In 2.7, reload re-initializes the module, undoing the removal.  Hence

```
>>> reload(sys)
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> sys.setdefaultencoding
<built-in function setdefaultencoding>
```

EDIT: Irrelevant material removed and the following correct answer added.

As to the print problem: reload **also** undoes IDLE's modification of the output streams.  This disables print commands.  They execute (don't raise) but nothing is actually sent.

```
>>> print 'abc', u'abc'
>>>
```

The above is after reload but before calling the revived setdefaultencoding.  I plan to add a note to the IDLE doc warning that reloading sys disables IDLE by undoing its modifications thereof.